# How do I create a JavaScript UI with drag and drop to create a 'Nested Set Modal'?

Tags: javascript, tree

Emulating a graphic from Mike Hillyer's blog post on [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), I would like to create a user interface in JavaScript that allows users to drop and drag hierarchical data into a Nested Set Model.

[image: Nested Set Model]

Are there any examples or demos of JavaScript and/or jQuery apps that accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

try using a file tree,

i done one myself, simple and powerfull, check this [drag and drop demo](http://jtree.tk/drag-and-drop/demo)

i need update the github repo yet, but you can add to the plugin this small function to allow json export (here it assume values not get any quote)

```
    $.fn.jtreeGetJson = function()
    {   var t = $(this).children('li');
        var json = '[';
        t.each(function(n,e)
        {   if(n>0) json += ',';
            json += '{';
                var span = $(e).children('span');
                json += '"label":"'+span.html()+'"';
                var ref = span.data('ref');
                if(ref !== undefined) json += ',"ref":"'+ref+'"';
                /*var d = span.data('info'); if(d === undefined) d = {};
                if(!$.isEmptyObject(d))
                {   json += ',"data":{';
                    var nb=0;
                    $.each(d, function(n,v){ if(nb++) json += ','; json += '"'+n+'":'+'"'+v+'"'; });
                    json += '}';
                }*/
                var u = span.next('ul');
                if(u.length)
                {   json += ', "subs":';
                    json += $.fn.jtreeGetJson.call(u);
                }
            json += '}';
        });
        json += ']';
        return json;
    }
```